# OpenCV+CUDA simultaneously linked with Python and a Python C extension

Tags: python, c++, c, opencv

I'm working on a Python project that involves C extension code, and opencv is directly used in both the Python code and C extension code, both requiring CUDA. This is proving to be very tricky to setup in terms of dependencies and linking, and so I'm hoping others might have insight after spending considerable time without much progress myself. In particular I have a few questions:

1. Building opencv from source with shared lib + Python support, and linking the C extension with the produced libraries, seems to allow both the Python and C extension to work, but a maintainer seemed to say this is very bad and may cause weird conditions due to shared state. Are there specific areas where problems arise and is this a bad idea to do?
2. The only obvious alternative I can see to 1) is to have Python import one opencv and have the C extension load another opencv build. Is this feasible to do on Linux and Windows without doubling the very large amount of memory consumed in loading opencv?

3. Are there feasible general options I'm overlooking? (Hopefully involving pip wheels to save a several-hour build per install)

Comment: For #1, why do you need to build your own? The standard Windows builds come with everything needed, and on Debian i can get standard packages for everything as well. | For #2, what do you mean by "very large amount of memory"? From what I've seen, even the monolithic OpenCV builds don't use anything significant given common memory sizes available these days. | Please, give us more info about what you're exactly trying to do, and how you intend to deploy/ship this.

Comment: @DanMašek For #1, the main problem is that we need CUDA support (important detail I forgot to mention, edited question). Building from source works except that it takes several hours on stuff like nvidia jetson hardware, which motivated me to try to generate a CUDA pip wheel with python-opencv repo. That worked but precludes production of libopencv*.so files needed by the C extension, and I also saw mention of potential issues inherent to double-linking like this.

Comment: Importing cv2 appears to add 1GB+ to memory usage and I figure without sharing the libraries that would be doubled but that is just speculation

Comment: Ok, ths CUDA support is significant, good that you mentioned that and updated the question. Can't validate your observations regarding memory usage of that, since I don't use that. | What's the particular deployment scenario you're going to deal with? Seems to me that on most platforms, you'll need your own custom-built OpenCV for both your extension as well as the main interpreter. Would it, perhaps, make more sense to ship the whole thing pre-built? A package with Python virtual env that has everything it needs, or perhaps something like a Docker image?

Comment: @DanMašek Thinking about it, there's no real reason why shipping a venv wouldn't work as long as it's per-CUDA version I think. I didn't think of that and will try thanks! Docker will be a big task. If you answer I will accept your answer